Producing non-OEM parts?
I run a small business on the side and I work professionally as an industrial automation mechanic. Part of my job is rebuilding the machines and replacing wear components. One of the assemblies I pull apart has a nylon body to it that wears over time, when I asked why we do not just replace them, I was told that the OEM refuses to sell that individual piece. I think the point is so you have to buy an entirely new assembly. I found the patent that this assembly is under but the patent is for the system as a whole it seems. How can I tell if I would be able to reproduce this part and sell it? Who do i need to talk to to make sure I'm not violating any patents? Any info is appreciated! Thanks in advanced
Link to patent https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/158-876-787-730-118/frontpage?l=en

If you would list the patent number we can help you a lot more.

First, it is important that you are actually looking at a patent and not the corresponding application. People commonly make that mistake. Second you need to check whether the patent is still in force. Patents expire and sometimes required fees aren't paid. If you had listed the patent number we could have easily helped you with that. Assuming you really have a patent and it is active, you then read the claims. If the part incorporates each and every part of any individual claim then it infringes. The claims and only the claims cover what it protected. Reading and assessing claims is not simple for non-lawyers.
Assuming the individual part is not covered by a claim you avoid infringement of this patent. Avoiding one patent does not guarantee you don't infringe other patents. To be safe you should do a patent search. There are techniques, but you can start by reading other patents referenced by the patent you have and other patents held by the OEM. Larger companies use patent attorneys to help with freedom to operate assessment.
Update based on cited documents:
You provided in comments and the edited question, two documents. One US patent and one application. I looked at the independent claims and they cover a complex assembly of parts, not just a plastic bushing. Thus, I'd guess if you only produce the bushings you are clear from infringement from the two cited documents. However, I can't be sure there aren't more patents either by the OEM or by the manufacturer of the bushings.
There are potential other questions such as whether the customers of the conveyer systems are contractually required to use the OEM for service and whether there are "Right to Repair" laws in effect. These are beyond the scope of Ask Patents.
I am not a lawyer so this isn't legal advice. As always I encourage you to consult with an actual attorney.

9079717 is the patent number. I am using lens.org and it states it is active. I will start reding through the claims now. I will also start looking at the rest of the patents that the OEM holds, thank you for the advice.

@Dreist That is a real patent and it is active. US patents are usually listed with like this: US9079717B1. It would be best to add it to your question and link it to Google Patents: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9079717B1/en?oq=US9079717B1  When I have time, I'll add to my answer.

@Dreist By the way, lens.org is a good site for patent searching.

I found a patent that is pending that matches up to what we have a lot better. I put the link in my post. The assembly listed there is a lot closer to what we use but it is still not exactly what we have.
